# Get a reference to the current class (ascx or aspx) given a member object

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Given an instance of a control `SomeControl` that is in a some file (could be a usercontrol/ascx, or an aspx) how can I get a reference to the class to which it belongs?

In a usercontrol, `SomeControl.NamingContainer` seems to be reliable.

In a page that inherits from a MasterPage, this will return a reference to the `ContentPlaceHolder`, not the actual class that defines the aspx. What I would want in that case is `SomeControl.Page`

`Parent` will return the parent control in the heirarchy so isn't much use.

Is there any method for getting this directly regardless of what kind of thing it is?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference to the class to which it belongs"?  Giving some details as to what you are trying to do and why you need it would help, I don't quite follow...

Comment: Every control is a member of a class. When you create a control `SomeControl` in `default.aspx` then it becomes a member of class `default`, e.g. `default.SomeControl`. Given `SomeControl` I want a reference to `default`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between being a member of a class, and being an addressable control on a page.  There's a difference - one is a property of an object oriented programming language, the other is a construct added to the WebForms implementation of ASP.NET.

Adding a control to default.aspx adds that control to the page's Controls collection.  A reference is then automatically added by the designer, to the page class, as long as the control in question is not contained in another controls template (or if that template is marked as an InstanceTemplate like a ContentPlaceholder).  The reference is basically a shortcut around Page.FindControl.

A control's NamingContainer is the first ParentControl that is responsible for ensuring the uniqueness of controls inside of it, by implementing INamingContainer interface.

It sounds like what you're trying to do is find the Page a control is associated with?  To do that, you'd want to traverse the control tree (follow the .Parent property on each control), checking if the parent is of type Page.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't completely clear. The object in question will *always* be a member of the class, not something added dynamically to the control tree. `Page` is not good enough, because if it's a usercontrol, I want the class that defines the usercontrol, not the page. (A control in a userControl is not a member of the Page class, it's a member of the usercontrol class).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the Parent property, and in a recursive fashion:

```
public Control GetParent(Control ctl)
{
  Control parent = ctl.Parent;

  while (parent != null)
  {
     if (parent is UserControl || parent is Page)
        return parent;

     parent = parent.Parent;
  }

  return ctl.Page;
}
```

Something like that.  This is the only way to identify the parent container of a control, whether its in a UC or a Page.  A control can only identify the page, not the user control it belongs to, except through the Parent property.

HTH.